# Create game room in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, android-room, office-online-server

I would like to create a gaming Xamarin app which involves creating a room containing 2 users connected at a time(Like chess). Is there a simplest free way or simple logic using framework tools for creating a server room?

Comment: You should try develop with unity3D or something like that, Xamarin is not a recommended way to create a gaming app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will look into it :)